# Shuffling pointers to pointers to structs

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault, shuffle

There are 2 structs in my code; `card(value, suit)` and `deck(**cards, n)`, and I am trying to shuffle the cards inside the deck.

Inside the for loop of the `shuffle()` function.

The ith card after the first card is saved at `temp_card`.

A random card is selected and assigned to ith card.

`temp_card` is assigned to the random card.

The problem is program stops execution at this line probably with a segmentation fault.

```
**(d->cards + i) = **(d->cards + random_number);
```

I tried to debug with gdb, but it wasn't very specific. This is the code. I also added some cards and deck to `main()` in order to test it but I'm pretty new to C so I might also be screwing up the memory locations of those pointers.

Is my approach to shuffling correct, or should I change it, and why program stops at that line, is it because the pointers I provided are invalid?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define VALUE_ACE 14
#define VALUE_KING 13
#define VALUE_QUEEN 12
#define VALUE_JACK 11

typedef enum {
  SPADES,
  HEARTS,
  DIAMONDS,
  CLUBS,
  NUM_SUITS
} suit_t;

struct card_tag {
  unsigned value;
  suit_t suit;
};
typedef struct card_tag card_t;

struct deck_tag {
  card_t ** cards;
  size_t n_cards;
};
typedef struct deck_tag deck_t;

void shuffle(deck_t * d){   

    card_t temp_card;
    int n = d->n_cards;
    int random_number;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){

        temp_card = **(d->cards + i);

        random_number = rand() % n;

        **(d->cards + i) = **(d->cards + random_number);
        **(d->cards + random_number) = temp_card;
    }       
}

int main(){
    deck_t deck;

    card_t card1;
    card1.suit = 1;
    card1.value = 1;
    card_t *c_ptr = &card1;
    card_t **c_pptr = &c_ptr;

    card_t card2;
    card2.suit = 2;
    card2.value = 2;
    card_t *c_ptr2 = &card2;
    card_t **c_pptr2 = &c_ptr2;

    card_t card3;
    card3.suit = 0;
    card3.value = 5;
    card_t *c_ptr3 = &card3;
    card_t **c_pptr3 = &c_ptr3;

    card_t card4;
    card4.suit = 2;
    card4.value = 2;
    card_t *c_ptr4 = &card4;
    card_t **c_pptr4 = &c_ptr4;

    deck.cards = c_pptr;

    deck.n_cards = 4;

    deck_t *d_ptr = &deck;

    shuffle(d_ptr); 
}
```

Comment: You've only put one card into `deck.cards`, not all 4 cards.

Comment: `deck.cards = c_pptr;` has only one card in the deck. Why do you need double `*` pointers?

Comment: Aside: after defining the suits with `enum` you ignore that and use `0`, `1` etc.

Comment: @WeatherVane It's a course assignment and I am supposed to do this with pointers to pointers, so how can I add those pointers to deck after the first card just like an array?

Comment: You probably need  array of `card_t struct` and store the address of array in `deck_t struct ` in single pointer not double pointer.

Comment: Besides the point, but the shuffle would be more random if it didn't touch already-shuffled cards, i.e., for each position choose a random card between that and the last card, inclusive.

Answer (score 1):

You assign the cards with `deck.cards = c_pptr` but `c_pptr` is only a pointer to the first card pointer. Yet you assume that `cards + i` will magically find the other card pointer pointers related to that first card pointer, but nothing in the code supports this. Using a card analogy: you have four cards scattered in different places, you take one of those cards and then you expect to be able to draw the next card from that "deck", but you are holding only the one card.

For indexing (with `*(cards + i)` or the equivalent `cards[i]`) to work, you need to allocate an *array* for the pointers to cards, populate those pointers with the addresses of your cards, and assign a pointer to the first element of the card pointer array to `cards`. The array, such as `card_t *card_ptrs[4]`, is what makes indexing work - the contents are consecutive in memory, not unlike cards in a deck.

However, the second layer of pointers is unnecessary: you can just allocate an array of *cards* (not pointers to cards) and assign the pointer to the first card to `cards` (removing the second `*` from it and all other places you have it).

Comment: (BTW, having to speak of things like "card pointer pointers" is often a good indicator that the code might be unnecessarily complicated.)

Answer (score 1):

As it has already been pointed out in comment (from Barmar & Weather Vane), your code doesn't insert 4 cards into the deck. Only the first card is inserted while the remaining three cards have no relation to the deck.

What you need to do is to use dynamic allocation so that you can allocate an array of cards. The size of the array has to match the number of cards in the deck.

But first... It seems strange to use a double pointer in the deck. So start by changing it into a "single" pointer - like:

```
struct deck_tag {
  card_t * cards; // Only one *
  size_t n_cards;
};
```

Then in `main` do something like:

```
int main(){
    deck_t deck;
    deck.n_cards = 4;
    deck.cards = malloc(deck.n_cards * sizeof *deck.cards);
    if (!deck.cards) exit(1);

    // Now you have 4 cards in the deck and you can 
    // insert card values directly into the deck.
    // There is no need for variables like card1, card2, card3 ...
    deck.cards[0].suit = 1;
    deck.cards[0].value = 1;

    deck.cards[1].suit = 2;
    deck.cards[1].value = 2;

    ... and so on (or better... use loops)


    shuffle(d_ptr); 

    free(deck.cards);
    return 0;
}
```

Also you'll need to update the shuffle code to use a "single" pointer.

Comment: I wasn't comfortable with double either but the course enforces me to do it that way in order to teach how to shuffle pointer addresses

Comment: @gunessun Are you saying that you are not allowed to change `struct deck_tag`? If so that information (i.e. that `struct deck_tag` must use double pointers`) should have been part of your question. For this specific application I don't see any purpose/benefit of using double pointers. Consequently my advice is to get rid of them and instead use a more simple approach. There are cases where it makes sense to use double pointers and "shuffle" pointers instead of shuffling elements but this is not one.